# A limit question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim _{x\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle \int _0^{x^2}(\sin t)^{\frac{3}{2}} dt}{\displaystyle\int ^x_0t\left(t-\sin t\right)dt}$$

How to solve this limit problem?
Notice that the numerator is $(\sin t)^{\frac32}dt$.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: I don' think this question was closed fairly. There is no context needed in this case, it is not an IT question, it is a clear mathematical problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

Start using the fundamental theorem of calculus which gives:

$$\frac d {dx}\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,dt=2 x f\left(x^2\right)$$

$$\frac d {dx}\int_0^{x}g(t)\,dt=g(x)$$

So, the expression is:

$$A=\frac{2 \sin ^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(x^2\right)}{x-\sin (x)}$$

Now, consider Taylor series for $\sin(y)$ or L'Hopital.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: thank you :) I follow you steps and reach the correct answer(the answer is 12) .

Comment: You are welcome ! You obtained the good result. May be, you could edit the post and show your solution. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\;dt=f(x)$$
and:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2} f(t)\;dt=2x f(x^2)$$
you can just use L'Hopitals rule, as the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by using L'opital rule.
Differentiate both num. and denominator.
After that, put sinx in denominator , $$\sin x= x-  \frac{x^3}{3!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: both of the numerator and the denominator are easily integrable functions. Simply integrate them, and then use the L'Hospital rule.

*Extension: applying the l'Hospital rule you will derive functions which you've just integrated. So you can probably largely reduce your work if you spare the optimization of the resulting formulas after the integration.*

Comment: Can you sub in $x = 0$ immediately and conclude that an indeterminant term, $0/0$, is produced, then follow up with L'Hopital's Rule? (which may involve a fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: @JesterTran No, you can't do that because if you sub $x=0$, you will get a $\frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined. L'Hospital rule works only if there if a "limes of type $\frac{0}{0}$", but not on $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: I'm not understanding your point. What is the difference between "limit of type $0/0$" and $0/0$? As long as the limit is in an indeterminant form, then L'Hop's can be used.

Comment: @JesterTran For example, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x}=1$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: Sub in $x=0$ to get the indeterminant form, $0/0$. Apply L'Hop since to get $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1}$ which is equal to $1$. 

If you sub in $x = 0$ and get an undefined/indeterminant form, then you can calculate the limit via L'Hop

Comment: @JesterTran Well, maybe I don't know (or don't understand) the indeterminant form, but I think it could be a little bit problematic, because in the case of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2x}{x}$ we would get also $1$.

Comment: Indeterminant form is $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ and on my most recent comment, it was meant to say indeterminant instead of undefined because they are two different things. As for the limit, it gives $2$ not $1$

Comment: @JesterTran Ok, I think I understand you. Unfortunately, during my studies I've learned from the indeterminant forms only a little bit. Integrating these indeterminant forms seems probably over my current skills, although I think already that you have right. But my version (first integrate, and then l'Hospital) also solves the question?

Comment: Cool! Yeah, your method works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @JesterTran Thank you! :-)